# Как изнутри узнать айди iframe-родителя?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

```
<iframe src="1.php" id="1"></iframe>
<iframe src="1.php" id="2"></iframe>
```

А в 1.php скрипт, но он берёт id первого iframe, а нужно чтоб своего родителя:

```
$('html').attr('id', $('iframe',top.document).attr('id'));
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`frameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement) чтобы получить доступ к элементу, содержащему текущую страницу:

```
$('html').attr('id', frameElement.id);
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо, почитаем сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так попробуйте.

```
<iframe src="1.php?id=2" id="2"></iframe>
```

Что делать дальше - надеюсь, понятно.

Comment: Вопрос был не об этом. Там у меня регуляркой отрубается весь гет. Спасибо.

Comment: @StanislawKukaew А вы не отрубайте!